# SVM non-linear decision function using hyperline

Tags: svm, nonlinear

Suppose that we have a toy classification problem *X* -> *y*  in 2D. In scikit learn, I solve this question with

X = np.array([[2, 1], [3,1], [3, 0], [4, 0], [5, -1]])
y = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0])
from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = svm.NuSVC(kernel='sigmoid')
clf.fit(X, y)
clf.predict(X)

Is there any way to calculate class prediction for a new sample point X<sub>i</sub> using only hyperline formula without using alphas of support vectors?

Similarly, is there any way to calculate hyperline from support vectors in kernel space so that a new sample will be predicted by a simple calculation wx-b>1 or wx-b<1 formula?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what are you asking precisely but SVM works with the support vectors, since the power of this tool is finding the best separating hyperplane, the support vectors are used in order to define the margin. I don't know exactly what do you mean by "not using alphas" but in order to predict the correct label for new fresh data points you are going to use the relation that you wrote that already uses the alpha since it guarantees that your data points will be outside the margins. If you use Soft-SVM instead you can allow some points to being inside the margin introducing some slacks variables.
In your particular case you need to apply a kernel function in order to linearly separate your data, but again even in that space, SVM will find the best separating hyperplane using the margin and the alpha, and when you compute the label for your new data points you are going to use a formula that already consider alpha.